# caching images from json in listview?

Tags: java, android, json

I followed this lesson [here](http://www.wingnity.com/blog/android-json-parsing-and-image-loading-tutorial/) which talk about json parsing and image loading in list view the example works good but it has a problem in imageview when scrolling up & down all images reloading so can anyone solve this problem?

this the adapter of listview

```
    package com.wingnity.jsonparsingtutorial;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actors> {
    ArrayList<Actors> actorList;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public ActorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        actorList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
            holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            holder.tvDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDescriptionn);
            holder.tvDOB = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDateOfBirth);
            holder.tvCountry = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);
            holder.tvHeight = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvHeight);
            holder.tvSpouse = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSpouse);
            holder.tvChildren = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvChildren);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(actorList.get(position).getImage());
        holder.tvName.setText(actorList.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvDescription.setText(actorList.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.tvDOB.setText("B'day: " + actorList.get(position).getDob());
        holder.tvCountry.setText(actorList.get(position).getCountry());
        holder.tvHeight.setText("Height: " + actorList.get(position).getHeight());
        holder.tvSpouse.setText("Spouse: " + actorList.get(position).getSpouse());
        holder.tvChildren.setText("Children: " + actorList.get(position).getChildren());
        return v;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageview;
        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvDescription;
        public TextView tvDOB;
        public TextView tvCountry;
        public TextView tvHeight;
        public TextView tvSpouse;
        public TextView tvChildren;

    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Used the Android Universal Image-Loader This is best**

> Declare

```
    private ImageLoader imageLoader1;
```

> On Create

```
 imageLoader1 = ImageLoader.getInstance();

 imageLoader1.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity()));
```

> no_image here a drawable image without any image load in Cache

```
   DisplayImageOptions
            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.no_image) // resource or drawable
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_image) // resource or drawable
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.no_image)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

    imageLoader1.displayImage(yourpath.replace(" ", "%20"), ivprofile, options);
```

**You Can Use Piccaso Also and Glide also**

Answer (score 0):

here is the code after editing it works like a charm

```
    import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

public class ActorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Actors> movieItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public ActorAdapter(Activity activity, List<Actors> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.flag);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rank);

        // getting movie data for the row
        Actors m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getImage(), imageLoader);

        // title
        title.setText(m.getName());


        return convertView;
    }

}
```